# javascript for listbox items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please suggest how can i override the item in the list if it is already available in the list when user moves from one listbox to other list box.

Comment: why are you pre-loading the list/select on the right?

Comment: I'm not preloading , its like user can select the items from the left hand side list box and user can view the selected items in the right hand side list box. @DavieBrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use jquery insertAfter

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.addtoright').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#s option:selected').each(function(){
            if( $('#d option:contains("'+$(this).text()+'")').length > 0){ 
                $(this).remove();
            }else{
                if($('#d option').length > 0){
                   $(this).insertAfter('#d option:last');
                }else{
                    $(this).appendTo('#d');
                }            
            }
        });
    });
    $('.addtoleft').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#d option:selected').each(function(){
            if( $('#s option:contains("'+$(this).text()+'")').length > 0){ 
                $(this).remove();
            }else{
                if($('#s option').length > 0){
               $(this).insertAfter('#s option:last');
                }else{
                    $(this).appendTo('#s');
                }
            }
        });
       });
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/bwc3yqme/4/)

Dont forget to add class addtoright to right arrows and addtoleft to left arrows

Comment: But its not overriding the item if the item is existing in the list. Example, Afghanistan is already available in both the list, again when i add to right hand side, it should override the exising one but not to display again. Its showing twice in the list when i add them. My requirement is to override the item if its already available. Thanks. @Mohamed-Yousef